# Data-has-video attribute on html

Tags: html, video, attributes

So, I was taking a look at some websites that display video on their front page, and I came across [this](http://maaemo.no) website. I wanted to know how they had accomplished such a remarkable result, so I inspected the element that contained the video. To my surprise, I encountered html attributes I had never seen before.

My question is: If this is not standard html, then what is it?, and how can I use it?

Here is a snippet of the code they are using:

```
<div class="frontpage-head-wrapper" data-has-video="1" data-video-mp4="http://d27shkkua6xyjc.cloudfront.net/videos/maaemo-film-2.mp4?mtime=20141113185431" data-video-ogv="http://d27shkkua6xyjc.cloudfront.net/videos/maaemo-film-2.ogv?mtime=20141113185421">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are data attributes. They are useful because they are standardized, and
allow easy JavaScript access:

```
ch = document.querySelector('div').dataset;

// 1
ch.hasVideo;

// http://d27shkkua6xyjc.cloudfront.net/videos/maaemo-film-2.mp4?mtime=20141113185431
ch.videoMp4;

// http://d27shkkua6xyjc.cloudfront.net/videos/maaemo-film-2.ogv?mtime=20141113185421
ch.videoOgv;
```

[Using data attributes](http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

A point before I answer your question is that the **data** attributes are custom attributes in which user can store any data. These were introduced in HTML5. For more information please refer to this 
From what I understand looking at the code  link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Now to your question

what happens is that the website is using custom data attributes and the custom attributes specifies the url where the video is stored. And when I dug further in the code, I found that they are displaying video using ajax calls

Comment: I saw that too. In this function: FrontpageHandler.prototype.initialize, right?